# Canonical partition function

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

I have a question regarding the addition of a constant energy in the Hamilton when we compute the Canonical partition function. In my script it is said that even if we add a constant value of energy, the entropy won't change? How is that possible?

Is it because if you try to find the entropy from the free energy (sackur tetrode equation) that added energy will be divided by the number of particles of the system?

How does the entropy stays the same?

Comment: sry i don't know how to properly write latex here. But basically in my entropy formula i always and up with a factor -betaE_0 / N . And i say that assuming this factor is to small we can neglect it and  we end up with the same formula for entropy

Comment: where is the checkmark?

Comment: i think i did??

Comment: your's did because you used the same methode that i did. That was the only reason for the upvote. But the other one is also good, that way i know another method on how to reach to the same results. Btw how can i chat with someone, when i want to know something that doesn't necessarily needs a thread ?

Comment: so i randomly pick a chat and ask my question xD ?

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for MathJax tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the quantum canonical ensemble partition function:

$$Z\equiv \mathrm{Tr}\,e^{-\beta H} \quad , $$

where $\beta=1/T$ ($k_\mathrm B = 1$) is the inverse temperature and $H$ the Hamiltonian. The entropy associated to a density operator $\rho$
is defined as

$$S[\rho]\equiv -\mathrm{Tr} \,\rho\ln \rho \quad . $$

Some algebraic manipulations show that for the equilibrium density operator

$$ \rho_{\mathrm{eq}} \equiv \frac{1}{Z} \, e^{-\beta H}$$

this yields

$$ S_{\mathrm{eq}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial T}\, (T\ln Z) \quad .$$

Now if we replace $H\rightarrow H + c$, where $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant, then $Z \rightarrow Z\, e^{-\beta c}$ and consequently

$$ S_{\mathrm{eq}} \rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial T}\, (T\ln ( Z\, e^{-\beta c})) = \frac{\partial}{\partial T}\, (T\ln Z) + \frac{\partial}{\partial T}\, (-T\beta c) = \frac{\partial}{\partial T}\, (T\ln Z) = S_{\mathrm{eq}} \quad . $$

Answer (score 1):

In canonical ensemble, the partition funciton $Z(T, V, N)$ is directly related to Helmholtz free energy:

$$F = -KT \ln Z(T, V, N) \tag{1}$$,

and energy:

$$\tag{2}
  U = \frac{\sum_i E_i e^{-\beta E_i}}{Z} = -\frac{\partial \ln  Z}{\partial \beta}.
$$

Then, the entropy

$$\tag{3}
  S = \frac{U - F}{T}.
$$

Therefore, if all energies shift by a constant $\xi$, them energy $U$ in Eq. (2) will shift by the constant:
$$
  U \Longrightarrow \,\,  \frac{\sum_i (E_i+\xi) e^{-\beta (E_i+\xi)}}{Z} = U+\xi.
$$
and also the partition function and the Free energy $F$
$$
Z \to \sum_i e^{-\beta (E_i+\xi)} = e^{-\beta \xi} Z .\\
F = -K_b T \ln Z \,\,\Longrightarrow\,\, -K_b T \ln Z + \xi 
$$
Thus,  the sntropy :

$$
  S = \frac{U - F}{T}\,\, \Longrightarrow \frac{U + \xi - F -\xi}{T}= \frac{U  - F }{T}.
$$

Therefore, two constants cancel each other, and entropy doesn't changed.

Comment: So is this formula that i tried to get your result (thx bttw)  $S= - \partial F / \partial T$ wrong ?

Comment: But by using that i got the sackur tetrode equation correctly, why is it wrong?

Comment: I misred. That is also ok.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. We are doing statistical mechanics without doing statistics, well we took mean and variance and we called it a day. Enough to understand QSM

Comment: One more thing, i assume this is also the case for any other type of generalized force correct ? Meaning they also do not change

Comment: I am not sure what general force is. A potential of a conservative force, the choice of the reference point introduces a constant to the potential.